# How to Achieve a checkerboard pattern combining two lists of items

Tags: php, algorithm, laravel, sorting, data-structures

I have users and posts, and I wish to display them in a checkerboard pattern on a web page, like this (where P is Post and U is User):

P - U - P - U

U - P - U - P

P - U - P - U

U - P - U - P

Whichever item is the 4th of a row will repeat as the 1st on the next row.

I will first get a list of all the posts, and a list of all users. I will then combine them into a larger list with the ordering applied.

I have written this in  PHP, but my current code just takes turns going P U P U like this:

P - U - P - U

P - U - P - U

P - U - P - U

P - U - P - U

Here is my code:

```
    $posts = Post::all()
    $users = User::all()

    $tiles = collect();

    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        $tiles->push($post);
        if ($users) {
            $tiles->push($users->pop());
        }
    }
```

I am looking for an efficient way to get the checkerboard pattern, I have been experimenting with using a counter and adding two posts or users at once when the counter%4 == 0, but nothing conclusive.

Comment: the real question here should be whether by any N'th field it will keep the order and to extract that endpoint to a function. will think about this one later on today, at work now lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry that I can't read php... but logically, apperently you need to push "user" before "post" on the even lines. So pseudocode would go something like:

```
if (lineno % 2 == 0) {
  push user; push post;}
else {
  push post; push user;}
```